# How to get from main activity in second activity?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am reading data from bluetooth in main activity using thread.
Also I want to show data in second activity continuously.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Starting a new activity android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267349/starting-a-new-activity-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

To show the data from main activity in the second, you have to pass it as intent  extra.

**MainActivity**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra(EXTRA1_TEXT, "This value one for ActivityTwo ");
i.putExtra(EXTRA2_TEXT, "This value two ActivityTwo");
```

**SecondActivity**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras == null) {
  return;
}
// get data via the key
String value1 = extras.getString(Intent.EXTRA1_TEXT);
if (value1 != null) {
  // do something with the data
}
```

Comment: not this way.Thread reading data continuously, i have to pass data to second activity instantly.

Comment: I didn't get it, be more concrete, what do you mean instantly and why?

Answer (score 0):

To communicate between activities you could use:

1. Custom intents
2. Events
3. Broadcasts